# Exit from Array.map() loop

Tags: node.js, express, promise, async-await, cheerio

I have following code

```js
const getCompanies = async (searchURL) => {
    const html = await rp(baseURL + searchURL);
    const businessMap = cheerio('a.business-name', html).map(async (i, e) => {
        const phone = cheerio('p.phone', innerHtml).text();
        if (phone == 123) {
            exit;
        }
        return {
            phone,
        }
    }).get();
    return Promise.all(businessMap);
};
```

I want to exit in loop if my condition match. is there any way so if condition match then return the data right away. and stop execution of the loop

Comment: is there an reason that you use `async` inside of `.map`

Comment: Becuase i am using await and then there are result will come

Comment: i dont see that you are using await

Comment: see second line   const html = await rp(baseURL + searchURL);

Comment: my question was why are you using `async` inside of `.map()` not on `rp`

Comment: Sorry, i am new into node. so i  just got code from internet

Comment: No Particular reason for the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223455/discussion-between-sunny-jindal-and-ifaruki).

Answer (score 2):

Your use case will be more suited to `Array.some` instead of `Array.map`

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

So it stops execution as soon as any of the item in the array matches the condition.
You can use an external variable alongside to catch the matched value, e.g:

```
const getCompanies = async (searchURL) => {
    const html = await rp(baseURL + searchURL);
    let businessMap;
    cheerio('a.business-name', html).some(async (i, e) => {
            const phone = cheerio('p.phone', innerHtml).text();

            if(phone == 123) {
               // condition matched so assign data to businessMap here
               // and return true so that execution stops
              return true;
            }       
       });
    return Promise.all(businessMap);
    };
```

Comment: i have to return values as well

Comment: I am fetching more data as well.. i need to return those data as well once condition is matched. but above code is not working for me :(

Comment: @sunnyjindal if you need to return all the matched values then you need to use `map` but if you need only the first matched value then above code assigns `bussinessMap` to the first matched and terminates the loop

Comment: Note that async function always returns a Promise, which will be regarded as `true`(i.e. the element passed the test), and make `.some(async ...)` stop execution after testing the first element.

For example, `[1, 2, 3].some(x => console.log(x))` prints 1, 2, 3 and returns false, but `[1, 2, 3].some(async x => console.log(x))` only prints 1 and returns true

Comment: @MetaPakistani . i need to return only one result if matched. but i have to return some value. i used your code but it;s not working

Answer (score 0):

businessMap is an array and there's nothing to await.
A simpler way to do this is:

```
const getCompanies = async (searchURL) => {
  const html = await rp(baseURL + searchURL)
  let $ = cheerio.load(html) 
  const ps = $('a.business-name p.phone').get()
  return ps.map(p => $(p).text()).filter(phone => phone !== '123')
};
```